# helm-M-x freezes and leaves large minibuffer after C-g

Tags: helm, spacemacs

Often I type a command like `C-x C-f` and then want to cancel it by pressing `C-g`. In normal emacs this was never a problem, but with `helm` I get a big minibuffer that says `Quit` and then shows some weird stuff. Pressing `C-g` more times doesn't fix anything. (If it matters, I'm using spacemacs in holy-mode, but I'm convinced this is a `helm`-specific issue).

**Demo**

After pressing `C-x C-f`:
[image]

After pressing `C-g` to cancel, the minibuf says `Quit` at the top and then displays:
[image]

If I press `C-g` more times I just get more `[No match]`s at the bottom. The only solution is to press `RET` until it opens some random file, which is of course undesirable behavior. This happens for all commands, not just `C-x C-f`.

Comment: Consider reporting a bug to the maintainers of the libraries. But just as hoping for hope here, it will help if you provide a step-by-step recipe to reproduce the problem(s), starting from `emacs -Q` (no init file).

Comment: The attached screen shots doesn't seems related to `helm`.

Comment: @Drew Instead of `emacs -Q`, consider using the provided `emacs-helm.sh` [script](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/wiki/Bugs), which sets up a minimal Emacs with vanilla Helm options.

Comment: @tianxiangxiong I've found that C-] works.